# Is it possible to run a python file from the command line, but interact with it? (REPL)

Tags: python, command-line, read-eval-print-loop

Suppose I have a very simple `test.py`, and here is the code:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b


print(sum(5, 6))
```

In my `cmd`, when I do `python test.py`, the command lines returns `11`.

What I would like to do is **interact** with it, so I want to type, `sum(4,2)` and the command line should return `6`, but instead I get:

`sum is not recognized as an internal or external command ...`

Basically I want to have the `REPL` feature, like `WingIDE`, `Sublime Text`. Is this possible from the command line?

Comment: type `python` in command line and it will run python interactively. You can then define `sum` as you do and call it, or import it from a predefined script.

Comment: Yes but how do I tell it I want it to call functions from the `test.py` file?

Comment: `from test import sum` but you have to make sure your system knows where to look for test.py (in case it's not in your working directory)

Comment: Thanks @Julien it worked

Comment: You can also use ``python -i test.py``, to leave it in interactive mode after the script finishes.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks I like this suggestion better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, you'd better pass input arguments when you run your program in cmd.
I put the code with minor modifications as below,

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b

import sys
a = int(sys.argv[1])
b = int(sys.argv[2])
print(sum(a, b))
```

Then in cmd, you just need to run like this:

**>> python test.py 4 2**

Comment: This works, but if I have multiple functions I don't think it does?

Comment: @VeeshaDawg would you give an example ? You mean passing same input arguments to different function?

Comment: What if I had more functions then just `sum`?